# I want to disable Gesture detection on particular area of a screen

Tags: android, swipe, gesturedetector

I am using this below code for swiping of activities

```
 SimpleGestureFilter detector=new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
         this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
       return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }
    @Override
     public void onSwipe(int direction) {

      switch (direction) {

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : 
                                                startActivity(new Intent(Temp_Activity.this, Length_Activity.class));
                                                overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left );
                                               break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT :  
                                            Intent intent=new Intent(Temp_Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right );
                                                     break;

      }
```

I am using this xml layout file with custom keyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/temp_act"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#808080" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/home_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/_temparature"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:ems="6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/clear_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/celsius_symbol"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewline1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="115dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
    android:background="#cccccc" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selection"
    android:text="@string/celsius_symbol"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/selection"
    android:text="@string/fahrenheit_symbol"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/selection"
    android:text="@string/kelvin_symbol"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:background="@drawable/selection"
    android:text="@string/rankine_symbol"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/lineview2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#cccccc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="1111"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/cel1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="1111"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/fah1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="1111"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/kel1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="1111"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/rankine1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"
    android:keyTextColor="#000000"
    android:shadowRadius="0.0"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

here when i apply gesture detector  it applied on custom keyboard also. 
I want to apply swiping on entire screen except custom keyboard there is any way to do like that.

thanks in advance

Comment: do you able to determine whether your custom keyboard is open or not? If you are able then you can make one check in on swipe method if custom key board is open then ignore to take any action on onSype() method.

Comment: Use `GestureOverlayView` for gesture detection. Group all views except the `keyboard` inside a container layout and add this container to the `GestureOverlayView`.

Comment: Actually my custom keyboard is by default open when i press on same button continuously button values are not displayed in text view it becomes sticky because of gesture detector